# Enabling auto-sizing for a UIButton disables the Image background

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autoresize

I dragged a dropped a `UIButton` onto my `Storyboard` and assigned it an image (from `Assets`).

I have a 10 MAX XS and have been using that for development. I'm now starting to dive into different screen sizes and have come across and issue with the `UIButton`.

I have used the auto-sizing section so it adjusts to screen sizes:

[image]

If I disable the Y axis arrow in the center square of autoresizing and run the emulator for a regular iPhone XS the button appears just fine and has adjusted for the width.

If I enable the Y axis the button does adjust to the right height BUT the image I use disappears!

Can anyone shed light on why this may be?

I have used the same image size in all three asset squares (1x, 2x and 3x) as a disclaimer just in case it's relevant.

[image]

Comment: Instead of autoresizing (the springs-and-struts arrows shown in your screen shot) I strongly recommend you use autolayout. Make this change before you go any further down the current road.

Comment: @matt thanks, I'll give this a go. Any pointers as to where to research it?

Comment: Uh, google maybe? Or even (gasp) read Apple's documentation?